# Normalizing Cloudwatch Log JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm trying to clean AWS Cloudwatch's log data, which is delivered in JSON format when queried via boto3. Each log line is stored as an array of dictionaries. For example, one log line takes the following form:

```
[
    {
        "field": "field1",
        "value": "abc"
    },
    {
        "field": "field2",
        "value": "def"
    },
    {
        "field": "field3",
        "value": "ghi"
    }
]
```

If this were in a standard key-value format (e.g., `{'field1':'abc'}`), I would know exactly what to do with it. I'm just getting stuck on untangling the extra layer of hierarchy introduced by the `field`/`value` keys. The ultimate goal is to convert the entire response object into a data frame like the following:

| field1 | field2 | field3 |
|--------|--------|--------|
| abc    | def    | ghi
(and so on for the rest of the response object, one row per log line.)

Last bit of info: each array has the same set of fields, and there is no nesting deeper than the example I've provided here. **Thank you in advance :)**

Comment: Can you show your effort?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using nested loops. Not my favorite - I always feel like there has to be a more elegant solution than crawling through every single inch of the object, but this data is simple enough that it's still very fast.

```
logList = [] # Empty array to store list of dictionaries (i.e., log lines)

for line in logs: # logs = response object
    
    line_dict = {}
    
    # Flatten each dict into a single key-value pair
    for i in range( len(line) ):
        line_dict[ line[i]['field'] ] = line[i]['value']
    
    logList.append(line_dict)

df = pd.json_normalize(logList)
```

For anyone else working with CloudWatch logs, the actual log lines (like those I displayed above) are nested in an array called `'results'` in the boto3 response object. So you'd need to extract that array first, or point the outer loop to it (i.e., `for line in response['results']`).

Answer (score 0):

This snippet demonstrates how to quickly go from a Cloudwatch Insights response to a cleaned up list of dictionaries that can be loaded into a dataframe:

```
# Retrieve a query result response from the boto3 cloudwatch logs client
response = logs.get_query_results(queryId)

# Reorganize the response data into a list of dictionaries
records = [dict({d["field"]: d["value"] for d in r}) for r in response["results"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

Details on the `get_query_results` function and the response structure can be found here:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs/client/get_query_results.html